# Does the definition of a low quality answer need to be expanded?

Tags: feature-request, answer-quality

When I see questions like this:  *[Coding style question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271039/coding-style-question)*  it makes me want to rip my hair out and scream obscenities involving the word "moron" at the OP. Someone who has asked 425 questions of varied complexity should know better.

What is worse is that the question has attracted 7 answers, and some of those have been upvoted! One of those looks like it has some merit, the others are just "me too, I like xyz" type answers, which add zero value to the community in any way.

So this question will be closed, but the garbage answers remain. Can they be deleted? More importantly, can we expand the definition of the low quality moderator flag so that it covers answers like these? (i.e. include text similar to the following:  *"... is not an answer, or adds zero value to the question/answer thread"*).

Comment: That user has been somewhat annoying with the constant questions.  They have 425 questions and 2 answers.  Off topic but this is one of the cases that would be fixed by limiting the amount of rep a user gets from questions.

Comment: While once I got a Nice Answer + Enlightened badge off one of his questions (pure luck I say), another time I caught him posting **5 one-line questions in the span of 10 minutes**, all being quickly closed of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't "not an answer" cover those answers then?

[image: Flag Dialog]

People flag non-answers this way all the time.

Comment: Thanks @Bill, i guess that should do the trick, although personally i would prefer to use the *low quality* flag.

Answer (score 1):

Vote to close as not a real question.